# Why did I got a Bad Request message when I used curl to send ifttt maker web request?

Tags: curl, webhooks, ifttt

As I mentioned at title. I use the following command in Windows 7 console with curl 7.51.0, the curl command return Bad Requests message to me:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"www.google.com"}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{MyChannel}/with/key/{MyKey}
```

It's quiet weird because I sent the command in my ubuntu VMware development environment (curl v7.35.0), the command reply OK, IFTTT action work well.

Also, I use the chrome plugin - Advanced REST client(ARC) to send the web request, it also reply OK, and IFTTT action work well.

Could anyone explain what's wrong with my curl application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer by myself. Base on by test result below, if I changed my command as :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {\"value1\":\"www.google.com\"} https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{MY_EVENT_NAME}/with/key/{MY_SLACK_API_KEY}
```

Then I would get a OK reply from IFTTT :

```
Congratulations! You've fired the {MY_EVENT_NAME} event
```

as you can see in the modified command, I've removed the single quotation marks embraced the json data and add some escape characters (back slash character'\') before double quotation marks.